# How to build a Terabyte queue?

Tags: queue, message-queue

How to build/design/program a Terabyte or Petabyte queue in memory? (Imagine a twitter like service with huge number of users.)

Comment: Please provide more information.  Are we talking queue, as in the data structure? What will be stored in this queue?

Comment: Correct pronunciation is tera, not terra.

Comment: yes exactly but size of queue is of the order of terabytes/petabytes?

Comment: queue can contain any info - any entry may be say text or binary or both - say limited to 1KB per entry.

Comment: Theoretically modern 64-bit architectures could make it possible to hold a terabyte or even a petabyte in RAM, but you're probably going to need custom hardware to get that much RAM into a machine. Putting it on disk on the other hand, or better yet spreading it over several servers is a far better option.

Comment: @Robert Davis: Considering the approximate going rate of $25 / GB (newegg.com), 1 petabyte would run about $25 million.  We're gonna need corporate sponsors! :)

Comment: ha! that is good estimation(in this post you are considering hard drive capcity not RAM, I suppose) . lets stick to terabyte only- then it will be 25k$ as I calculate.

Comment: @echo - maybe there's a REALLY good bulk discount out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use twitter's queuing service? It's called [kestrel](http://github.com/robey/kestrel) and it's open source.

Comment: do you have some idea of the queue size twitter have to deal with?

Comment: As their readme file says, kestrel is scalable "to infinity and beyond".

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend a lot on what file system you're using and what elements are stored in the queue. The elements of the queue will need to be addressable somehow.  Perhaps as filenames, or disk block addresses, or ... something.  You're going to need to store the *addresses* of these elements in the queue.  Depending on how many elements you're working with, you may even have to break it down even further and divide your queue up into blocks, where entire blocks of elements are considered one element in the queue, and each block is organized as its own sub-queue.

Comment: well, as long as you do adequate read-ahead.  You do have some amount of memory to work with, so as long as you keep enough queued data in main memory to serve up to clients it should work fine.  If your clients consume the data faster than you can retrieve it from disk, then you'll have a bottleneck. The only way around that is to do what Robert Davis suggested in a previous comment: spread it out over multiple servers.